# Разные результаты цифровой подписи с помощью System.Security.SignedCms и BouncyCastle CmsSignedDataGenerator

Tags: c#, signature, pkcs#12

Мне нужно сделать pksc#7 подпись для авторизации в системе ЕСИА.

У меня есть временами работающий код:

```
public static string SignSignedCms(string data)
{
    byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();

    certificate.Import(@"D:\...file.pfx", "pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(bData);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content);

    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
    signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("SHA256");

    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, true);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedCms.Encode()).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
}
```

Если data="asdfghjkl", то я получаю следующее:
MIIFbAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIFXTCCBVkCAQExDzANBglghkg...IRmmg0beHTRwKd - **1857 символов**

Результат **каждый раз один и тот же**.

Мне нужно делать тоже самое но другим способом (каждый раз после перезагрузки сервера я начинаю получать An internal error occured)

Я нашел BouncyCastle и класс в нем CmsSignedDataGenerator и написал вот такой код:

```
public static string SignBouncyCastle(string data)
{
    byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();

    certificate.Import(@"D:\...file.pfx", "pwd", 509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    AsymmetricKeyParameter key = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certificate.PrivateKey).Private;

    CmsSignedDataGenerator gen = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

    gen.AddSigner(key, DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate), CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha256);

    CmsSignedData cmsSignedData = gen.Generate(new CmsProcessableByteArray(bData));

    return Convert.ToBase64String(cmsSignedData.GetEncoded()).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
}
```

Этот код генерирует **каждый раз разный** результат типа такого:

MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANB...egV70FgAAAAAAAA - **811 символов**!

Оба метода должны генерировать "detached pkcs7-signature message", но BouncyCastle делает что-то другое.

SignedCms точно работает правильно (ЕСИА подпись принимает), а CmsSignedDataGenerator - нет.

Что мне нужно изменить в версии с BouncyCastle, чтобы получить правильную подпись?

SignedCms - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8412wc31%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

CMSSignedDataGenerator - https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html

я смотрю на описания классов и не вижу принципиальной разницы!